# How can I remove specified characters from a text file in r?

Tags: r, text

I am trying to compare two text files in R using `diffr`, but I know that one of the files I am comparing has a `carriage return` and curly brace '`{`' at the top of the text file and also a '`-}`' at the bottom.
How can I remove the carriage return and unwanted characters before my comparison?

I can read the text within the file using:

```
test<-readLines("C:\\Users\\examplefile.txt")
```

But after that I am unsure? Do I have to rewrite the file? I don't think I can use '`pattern`' to find what I want to delete as it's in two separate locations in the text?

In 'new.txt' I have this:

```
{ 
:some text here
-}
```

And in 'old.txt' I have:

```
:some text here
```

I'm using:

```
library(diffr)
diffr("old.txt","new.txt") to read the differences, but how do I extract the carriage return and braces first?
```

Comment: could you please provide a small version of your files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `head` and `tail` to remove the first two lines and last two lines.

```
new.txt <- tail(head(new.txt, -2), -2)

new.txt == old.txt
#[1] TRUE
```

Data:

```
new.txt <- readLines(textConnection("
{ 
:some text here
-}
"))

old.txt <- readLines(textConnection(":some text here"))
```

Comment: It's not removing the lines. When I `readLines` into `new.txt` the class of `new.text' is 'char. Does that matter?

Comment: I changed it to use `head` and `tail`. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `new.txt<-new.txt[-(1:2)]` to remove specified lines. I was going about this in a too complicated manner. Thanks for the direction.